# If SELECT COUNT is less than or equal to 10, input reservation details

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli, count

I'm trying to make a simple reservations form in PHP.

If the amount of bookings with the same date and time is less than or equal to 10, I want it to input the details to the table.

Anything else, I want a message to say "Booking failure! We're fully booked at that time."

**The issue:** I have 10 reservations on one specific date and time and the moment for testing, however all of my messages are coming back as "Booking failure! We're fully booked at that time." whatever the time. Nothing's being imported either.

I've tested the input process without a SELECT COUNT query and it successfully inputs, so I know something's wrong with my "less than or equal to" query.

I'd massively appreciate any help! Thanks

```
<?php 

require_once('lib/php/functions.php'); 
require_once('lib/php/db_connect.php');

//Grab Form Data
$reservationName = trim($_POST['reservationName']);
$reservationEmail = trim($_POST['reservationEmail']);   
$reservationNumber = trim($_POST['reservationNumber']);
$reservationDate = trim($_POST['reservationDate']);   
$reservationTime = trim($_POST['reservationTime']);   

$submit = trim($_POST['submit']);

$message = '';

if (!$db_server){ 
    die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    $db_status = "not connected"; 
}else{

    //If submit comment pressed, get data and input 
    if (isset($submit) && $submit == 'Submit reservation'){    

        if ($reservationName&&$reservationEmail&&$reservationNumber&&$reservationDate&&$reservationTime){

            $reservationName = clean_string($db_server, $reservationName);
            $reservationEmail = clean_string($db_server, $reservationEmail);
            $reservationNumber = clean_string($db_server, $reservationNumber);
            $reservationDate = clean_string($db_server, $reservationDate);    
            $reservationTime = clean_string($db_server, $reservationTime);
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); 

            $query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservations AS reservationCount WHERE reservationDate='$reservationDate' AND reservationTime='$reservationTime'"; 
            $result=mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 

            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            if ($row <= 10){

                $query = "INSERT INTO reservations (reservationName, reservationEmail, reservationNumber, reservationDate, reservationTime)
                          VALUES ('$reservationName', '$reservationEmail', '$reservationNumber', '$reservationDate', '$reservationTime')"; 
                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); 
                mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or 
                        die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)) . $query; 

                $message = "<p class='success'>Booking successful! See you soon.</p>";

            }else{ 

                $message = "<p class='fail'>Booking failure! We're fully booked at that time.</p>";
            }              

        }else{
            $message = "<p class='fail'>Booking failure! Please fill in all the fields.</p>";  
        }    
    }
}             
?>
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh come off it man, I'm a student and my learning process is ongoing.

Comment: You have two issues. 1) query is wrong and 2) result checking is wrong. Check my answer.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes Thanks Latheesan this has solved the issues

Comment: Its all right for you with learning and stuff. It's only Stack overflow is not your teacher. this site is to answer questions not to babisit students.

Comment: @YourCommonSense "this site is to answer questions". Correct and this is a question.

Comment: it is not. you are welcome to read rules first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your query is wrong. Update it to this:

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(*) AS reservationCount FROM reservations WHERE reservationDate='$reservationDate' AND reservationTime='$reservationTime'";
```

*Reason why your query was wrong was because, if you add `as reservationCount` after your table name, it becomes a table alias, not result field alias.*

Then update the code that does the check like this:

```
if ($row['reservationCount'] <= 10){
```

P.S. your code looks open to SQL Injection. Look into using MySQLi library in object orientated way and bind params to prevent sql injection.

Take a look at this example, it covers both recommendations: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working perfectly.
I'll tick it answered once I can!

Answer (score 1):

The `COUNT(*)` returns one single value in one single row, and you're checking for the number of rows, so it will always be true because `1 <= 10` is always true. Change it to:

```
if ($row[0] <= 10){
```

Comment: You're welcome. Latheesan Kanes' answer is good if you like to retrieve the value by name, but I personally prefer using the index when only a single value is expected. This allows you to make your query shorter (you can remove `AS reservationCount` because it is not required anymore) and reuse your code by copying `$row[0]` to other places without having to change the name between the brackets every time. As a bonus, retrieving the value by index is a bit faster, although this will be negligible for one value.